# How is nlme package in R "non-linear"?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, generalized-estimating-equations

Why is the package nlme non-linear?
Is it non-linear in the sense that gee is non-linear because of correlation structure/covariance pattern like exchangeable/AR1?

So if we drew out correlated errors i.e. in Toeplitz, AR(1) they wouldn't form a straight line?

Comment: Please note that you need to ask a clear statistical question. The package nlme contains multiple functions, and the different functions do different things. I assumed you to be asking about the model underlying the nonlinear fixed effects model (which could be fitted using the nlme function in the package of the same name), but Roland makes it clear that this assumption isn't justified. For the question to be both clear and on topic, you'll need to modify your post to ask about a specific *model*, and it will need to ask a clear question about that specific model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nonlinear mixed effects models are nonlinear in the same sense that "[nonlinear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression)" models are nonlinear - $E(Y|x_1,x_2,...,x_p) = f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\beta})$ is  nonlinear in the parameters (or in at least some of the parameters).

However, the model for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ can incorporate fixed and random effects, with those entering a model for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ linearly.

[You could think of nlme as extending nls models by adding mixed effects in the same way that lme extends ordinary regression models.]

Comment: The package contains functions for linear regression (`gls` to fit linear models with generalized least squares, `lme` for linear mixed-effects models) and for non-linear regression (`gnls` to fit non-linear models with generalized least squares, `nlme` for non-linear mixed-effects models).

Comment: @Roland If the question is really about "what does this package do" it's off topic. If it's about how a nlme model is nonlinear, it's on topic -- so if the above isn't an answer to the intended question, I believe the question's off topic. I'm happy to close it if need be.

Comment: I think OP might just be confused between the function `nlme` and the package nlme. But I'm not sure ... They refer to residual (auto-)correlation structures which can be used within the linear models offered by the package.

Comment: Right, yes, it may be confusion about that. That suggests it's probably off topic but I'll close as unclear for now; OP may be able to turn it into an on-topic post while clarifying what they need.